# Expect not matching

Tags: tcl, expect

I had an expect script that was working; it contained the following lines:

```
expect "\[Y\]\> "
send "n\r"
```

The OS I'm interacting with changed, I now have a mixed environment of boxes. Some now have "[Y]>", some have "[1]>" at the point I'm trying to deal with.

I tried changing the code to:

```
expect {
        "\[Y\]\> " { send "n\r";exp_continue }
        "\[1\]\> " { send "2\r";exp_continue }
}
```

however, running in debug I see:

```
"Choose the password option:
1. Mask passwords 
2. Plain passphrases
[1]>
expect: does "s...ses\r\n[1]> " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "[Y]> "? no 
"[1]> "? no
expect: timed out"
```

I don't understand why the revised code is not working, for either "[Y]> " or "[1]> ", when "[Y]> " was being matched before the 'else' statement was introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with escaping the square brackets which is special to `Tcl`.

```
# Using braces for pattern
expect {
    {\[Y]>} {puts Y}
    {\[1]>} { puts 1}
}
# or 
# Using double quotes
expect {
    "\\\[Y]>" {puts Y}
    "\\\[1]>" { puts 1}
}
```

We don't have to escape the closing bracket `]` and the symbol `>`

Comment: {\[1]> } { send "2\r"; exp_continue } worked for me. I was a little thrown by the "{puts Y}" in your example, as the strings to be sent are different, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Right, it is tricky that brackets are special to Tcl (command substitution) and both regexes and glob patterns (character sets).

Comment: If you want exact matching rather than the default glob matching, then specify that using the -ex flag: `-ex {[Y]> }`. That is much cleaner than adding backslashes to make glob do an exact match.